# UserControl cropped when used in MainWindow

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hello Stackoverflowers !

I'm creating a list with a searchbar in XAML, and when i tried to use my new UserControl in MainWindow.xaml, the Button in the UserControl is cropped in the designer instead of being resized to fit, why is that ?

Here is the MainWindow.xaml body :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <controls:SearchBox Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the body of the custom control :

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox 
        Grid.Row="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="Search"
        TextBlock.FontStyle="Italic"
        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
      />

    <!--   Content="{StaticResource FilterLogo}" -->
    <Button 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="Filter"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    </Button>


    <ListBox 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

    </ListBox>
```

I don't really know why my control is cropped to be honest. Any lead please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it doesn't fit.

You have two columns in your main window. Since you have not specified which column to place the UserControl, it defaults to the first column. But your `Width` definitions force that column to be one fourth the size of the second column.

Your `SearchBox` simply doesn't fit in the space you have allotted to it.

If you remove the star (*) from this line:

```
    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
```

...it will fit without being cropped. (Alternatively, you could place the user control in the second column, or expand the main window, or shrink the width of your UserControl.)

Comment: Oh right. So, taking into account what you both told me, i reduced the control width by half, and modified the size of the first column of the main window relative to the second column (a 30-70 ratio). It is a bit wider than expected but it will do the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When using stars in the column and row definitions, use them like percentages. Like this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*" /> <!-- 10% -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".9*" /> <!-- 90% -->
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This is what the XAML reader interpreted from your usage:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" /> <!-- 800% -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- 100% -->
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This will have undesired results.

Comment: Oh i didn't know, nice